# Why inotify-tools has different log format with the same config?

Tags: inotify

inotify config:

```
/usr/bin/inotifywait -e modify \
    -mrq --timefmt %a-%b-%d-%T --format '%w%f %T' \
/var/www/ | while read file; do
echo "$file " >> /var/log/inotify.log
```

============================================================================

files that updated with rsync from remote server have this format:

> /var/www/.index.php.3AYEV4 Wed-Sep-24-05:35:03

other files updated locally, they are good.

> /var/www/index.php Wed-Sep-24-05:35:03

why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format is the same, it is the file names that are different.

It is because the way rsync works by default - it first creates temporary files (like `.index.php.3AYEV4`) and when they are finished syncing, only then they get renamed to final filenames (like `index.php`). You can either modify your `inotifywait` to have `-e modify,move` or change upsteam rsync to not use temporary files by using `rsync --inplace` flag (but see [notes on --inplace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync))